# AndEngine HUD and Scene

Tags: android, andengine

Is it possible to drag a sprite from the HUD to the scene in AndEngine?  Basically, my game gives a "toolbar" of possible items for the user to drag from the HUD and place on the screen as static bodies, but I can't figure out how to do that.

I'm completely new to AndEngine, so if you can give any tips, ideas, or point me towards some tutorials for this sort of thing, that'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you plan to do things. HUD is just another scene on top of the main scene, so dragging Sprites should work as usual. When you release the touch, just detach the Sprite from HUD and attach it to the scene, it's as simple as that.

Regarding the physics body, you should create it at the same time. I have no idea what would happen if you created a Body connected to a Sprite attached to the HUD. Again, creating the Body is usual business.